# Directx 9 everything is blurred

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying out directx 9 for a personnal project, and everything i render (whether it's textures or texts) is blurred.
For example, I want to draw [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvZwu.png), and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9g0j.jpg) gets drawn. Same thing happens for text.
I don't know which part of the code could help you to see what's the problem, so ask more precisions if you need.

Comment: That texture is probably being upscaled. Why don't you try to do the same thing with a better texture?

Comment: I just used a texture that's 4 times bigger, and still blurry

Comment: There could be so many reasons behind it. What texture sampling filters are you using? You should also monitor the output of pixel shader

Comment: I tested all sampling filters i found, right now i'm using this: `SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_POINT)`

Comment: try linear or anisotropic. You should see better results

Comment: BTW did you try setting other texture sampling states for minification and magnification (D3DSAMP_MINFILTER and D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER) too? That sampling state only affects mipmaps

Comment: It seems that nothing has an effect

Comment: I'd recommend not using legacy Direct3D 9. Take a look at Direct3D 11 and in particular [DirectX Tool Kit's tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) particularly for ``SpriteBatch``.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of the well known half pixel offset problem. You can read about it here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx

There are different solutions to this but the most popular is to change how the vertex position is calculated and offset it by half a pixel.

If this doesn't fix the problem maybe you could post a comparison screenshot of the texture in some viewer and how it renders in your application, this could show what the problem is.